# Couldn't create HBITMAP from glReadpixels

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, glreadpixels, hbitmap

So here's a part of my code, what I'm trying to do is to make a HBITMAP from a OpenGl frame capture.

```
unsigned char *output = 0;
output = new unsigned char[WINDOW_WIDTH * WINDOW_HEIGHT * 3];

glReadPixels(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    output);

HBITMAP hdm = CreateBitmap(800, 800, 1, 32, output);
```

But my (HBITMAP)hdm is always NULL. Maybe there's another way to do that or what's wrong? I guess CreateBitmap would allocate memory itself, so the mistake must not be here. The output array seems to be fine though.

I've also tried the code from here: [Creating a HBITMAP from glReadPixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158289/creating-a-hbitmap-from-glreadpixels) but it didn't work as well, still getting NULL.

Would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Since the format of the pixel data is `GL_RGB`, the 3rd paramter of [`CreateBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183485(v=vs.85).aspx) should be 24 instead of 32. Or you have to use the `GL_RGBA` format. Did you debug the code? Does `output` receive any data?

Comment: Did you try calling `GetLastError`? What's the error code?

Comment: Rabbid76, thank you very much, it worked! Yes, output recieved the data. Your solution resolved the problem.

Comment: @joe_chip: Calling `GetLastError` after a call to [CreateBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485.aspx) returns a meaningless value.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th parameter of [`CreateBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183485(v=vs.85).aspx) is the number of bits required to identify the color of a single pixel.

Since the format of the pixel data is `GL_RGB`, the 3rd paramter of `CreateBitmap` has be 24 instead of 32. Note `GL_RGB`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` means 3 color components with each a byte, which leads to 24 bits:

```
HBITMAP hdm = CreateBitmap(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 1, 24, output);
```

Or you have to use the `GL_RGBA` format:

```
unsigned char *output = new unsigned char[WINDOW_WIDTH * WINDOW_HEIGHT * 4];
glReadPixels(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, output);

HBITMAP hdm = CreateBitmap(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 1, 32, output);
```

Note, If you use the `GL_RGB` format, you have to consider that [`CreateBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183485(v=vs.85).aspx) requires each scan line be word aligned.
The alignmnet for the [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) operation can be set by [`glPixelStorei`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glPixelStorei.xml), by setting the parameter `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`, which is by default 4, so this should not be an issue.
But you have to ensure that the dynamically allocated buffer is large enough:

```
size_t bpl = WINDOW_WIDTH * 3; // bytes per line
size_t r   = bpl % 4;          // rest of division by 4
bpl       += r ? (4-r) : 0;    // bytes per line aligned to 4
unsigned char *output = new unsigned char[bpl * WINDOW_HEIGHT];
```

or

```
size_t bpl = (WINDOW_WIDTH * 3 + 3) & ~3;
unsigned char *output = new unsigned char[bpl * WINDOW_HEIGHT];
```